# VBA code no longer working after changing to office 365

Tags: excel, vba

at work we recently had most of our computers updated to run the newer versions of Office, and this had made it so some code in my data sheets are not working. I have tried the code on a older version and it still works, the error I get is on `sws.Copy`
It says "Path/File access error '.\VBB331.tmp' " and then I get  Run-time error '1004'.
Any support and guidance on this would be greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const cESheets As String = "Front Sheet,Dimension Report,Dimension Report (2),Dimension Report (3),Drawing,Dimension Prinout,HFQ Report,Hardness Data"
    Const cSheet As String = "Front Sheet"
    Const cRange As String = "Q7:Q13"
    Const cCrit As Long = 1

    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim vntS() As String
    Dim iFound As Long

   
    vntS = Split(cESheets, ",")
   
    Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Trim(vntS(0)))
   
    ' Sum is incorrect, and CountIf doesn't work on non-contiguous cells.
    For Each Cell In sws.Range(cRange).Cells
        If Cell.Value = cCrit Then
            iFound = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Cell
    If iFound = 0 Then Exit Sub
   
    ' **********************************
    ' Copy Sheets to New workbook.
    ' **********************************
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    sws.Copy
    Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    iFound = 0
   
    For Each Cell In sws.Range(cRange).Cells
        iFound = iFound + 1
        If Cell.Value = cCrit Then
            sws.Parent.Worksheets(Trim(vntS(iFound))).Copy _
                After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next

    ' **********************************
    ' Export New Workbook to PDF
    ' **********************************

     With dwb
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Exported.pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Close False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your `sws.Copy` line supposed to be doing? It doesn't seem to get pasted at any time before the individual sheet copies potentially start.

Comment: I'm fairly new to VBA and had help setting this up, as far as I'm actually aware it is copying the require sheets and cells and pasting to an empty workbook and then publishing that new workbook to a PDF

Comment: The issue is that it works on the older versions of excel but not on our current version

Comment: [This](https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-discussion-misc-queries/119882-copying-worksheet-path-file-access-error-%5Cvbxxx-tmp.html) is an old similar question, but the last entry for a solution is recent.

Comment: Thanks for the help, changing the default save location has fixed this issue.

Comment: Cheers, I was curious if this was the problem. Would you mind adding the error to the title instead of "no longer working"? Because the link I referenced is old and for this problem this page would be the go-to as it can become more up-to-date. You can even add your example where you redirected the new save location, as you can answer your own question.

Comment: Oliver, as I asked above, would you mind updating the question and sharing the solution as an answer?