# Copy paste stopped working after upgrade to 365

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have bit of a code that has worked for a long time but it no longer works, we have recently been upgraded to 365, The code filers data on one worksheet then copies and paste into another worksheet but the paste no longer works. I am new to this so any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
This is the bit of code which is part of a longer module

```
 Application.StatusBar = "GENERATE LIST OF LICENSES DUE TO EXPIRE"
 
 Sheets("due to expire").Select
 Columns("A:I").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
 
 Sheets("Import").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
 Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
lngStart = Range("M1").Value 'assume this is the start date
lngEnd = Range("P1").Value 'assume this is the end date
Range("a1:I5000").AutoFilter field:=9, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
 Range("a1:i5000").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("due to expire").Select
 Range("a1").Select
 ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
 Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 
Number_of_Records = Sheets("Main").Range("L7").Value + 2
Selection_Range = Number_of_Records & ":1000000"
Rows(Selection_Range).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 
Number_of_Records = Sheets("Main").Range("L7").Value + 1
Selection_Range = "J2:J" & Number_of_Records
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection_Range)

Sheets("Import").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("C1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
```

Comment: Try avoiding `Select`: `Sheets("Import").Range("A1:I5000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("due to expire").Range("A1")`

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473778/vba-code-no-longer-working-after-changing-to-office-365), but anyway, please edit the question and detail what does 'no longer works' mean, do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i do not get an error message but the sheet where the data is pasted is blank

Answer (score 0):

It could be the date format has changed so add a message box to check.

```vb
Sub DueToExpire()

    Application.StatusBar = "GENERATE LIST OF LICENSES DUE TO EXPIRE"
    Dim wsImport As Worksheet, wsDue As Worksheet
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    
    Set wsDue = Sheets("due to expire")
    With wsDue
         .Columns("A:I").ClearContents
    End With
     
    Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")
    With wsImport
        lngStart = .Range("M1").Value 'assume this is the start date
        lngEnd = .Range("P1").Value 'assume this is the end date
         
         MsgBox "Start date is " & Format(lngStart, "d mmm yyyy") & vbLf & _
                "End date is " & Format(lngEnd, "d mmm yyyy")
         
        With .Range("A1:I5000")
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
             Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
            .Copy
            wsDue.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            .AutoFilter Field:=9
        End With
    End With
    
    Number_of_Records = Sheets("Main").Range("L7").Value + 2
    MsgBox "Number of records = " & Number_of_Records

    With wsDue
        .Rows(Number_of_Records & ":1000000").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("J2:J" & Number_of_Records - 1)
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, i ran the code and got the date pop up box but the sheet where the data is pasted is still blank

Comment: @alan I have added a message box to check number of records try that. I assume the dates shown are the correct ones.

Comment: Hi Thank you, the dates are correct, I have rerun the code and got the number of records msg but still not pasting data into designated sheet.